# What is difference between plus minus and minus plus

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I found a equation in my physics book of Omega ( In alternte current chapter) there is written both signs plus minus and minus plus , now I'm confused.

[image]

Comment: Nothing special... $\mp:=-(\pm)$

Comment: top with top and bottom with bottom.

Comment: Usually, this means that the two signs are related and negatives. So $\pm a\mp b$ means $+a-b$ or $-a+b.$

Answer (score 6):

When you see $\mp$, you will usually also see a $\pm$ somewhere in the same expression. It conventionally means that whatever sign you choose for one of them, you choose the opposite for the other. For instance, the expression $a\pm b\mp c$ represents the two options $a+b-c$ and $a-b+c$.

Comment: There is yet another use of $\mp$ like in: $a_0-a_1+a_2\mp\cdots$ where it indicates alternating signs, but starting with $-$, where $\pm$ would start alternation with a $+$.